# How to use database table for population of agents with parameter that is name of Space Markup Region parameter (converted from shapefile)?

Tags: database, location, anylogic, agent, population

In Anylogic I used a shapefile to import my own Regions into my GIS map. Then I converted the Shapefile into Space Markup. Now I can see my regions and if I click on it, it displays the correct name with "GIS Region" behind it.
(However if I search the name of my regions (e.g., "Region2") in my GIS Map, it doesn't find anything)

Now I want to create a population of agents (where they are all placed into a region), so I want to use a database table with the name of the Regions I imported into my map. However, when I create this population and run the model, the Regions are not found and the agents are just placed randomly in other countries...